# Yet another Nginx and PHP-FPM issue with 502 bad gateway error

Tags: php, nginx

I am installing a Nginx with PHP7 server on CentOS and like a lot of users I have the 502 bad gateway issue. I read all night long pages trying to solve my issue but I still have the same issue. I will explain it here so if somebody have some idea of what is going on, I would appreciate some help :-)

First of all the error logs from nginx and php-fpm. I use the "socket method" and I tried with the "network method" using 127.0.0.1:9000 but it didn't change anything... So I rollbacked the configuration. According to the logs, it does not seem to be an permission denied issue.

Note: The html pages are OK, the issue only appears with php pages.

nginx.log

```
2016/04/18 22:59:22 [error] 4705#0: *47 upstream sent invalid status "20 Site temporarily unavailable" while reading response header from upstream, client: 86.253.24.233, server: testvps.balusson.net, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "testvps.balusson.net"


2016/04/18 23:46:09 [error] 6115#0: *95 upstream sent invalid status "20 Site temporairement indisponible" while reading response header from upstream, client: 86.253.24.233, server: testvps.balusson.net, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "testvps.balusson.net"
```

But I don't see anything in the PHP-FPM logs

```
[root@vps263501 ~]# tail /var/log/php-fpm/error.log
[18-Apr-2016 21:46:48] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 8008
[18-Apr-2016 21:46:48] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[18-Apr-2016 21:59:41] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[18-Apr-2016 21:59:41] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[18-Apr-2016 22:11:12] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 2886
[18-Apr-2016 22:11:12] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[18-Apr-2016 22:11:15] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[18-Apr-2016 22:11:15] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[18-Apr-2016 22:11:15] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 2913
[18-Apr-2016 22:11:15] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

My configuration file is quite simple:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/maisonrt2012.conf

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name  testvps.balusson.net;

  root /var/www/maisonrt2012/public_html;
  index  index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Pass PHP scripts on to PHP-FPM
    location ~* \.php$ {
        try_files       $uri /index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }

        location /phpMyAdmin {
                root    /usr/share/;
                index   index.html index.htm index.php;
        }
}
```

The default.conf is set to the unix socket according to my sites-available configuration file

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;


    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }


    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /var/www/maisonrt2012/public_html/;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

In the nginx.conf file, the user is specified as nginx;

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
```

My PHP-FPM config file is as below
/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
; Start a new pool named 'www'.
[www]

user = nginx
group = nginx

;listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock

listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660

;listen.acl_users = nobody
;listen.acl_groups =

listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
```

The location of www.sock is OK with the nginx user and rights

```
[root@vps263501 ~]# ls -l /run/php-fpm/
total 0
srw-rw---- 1 nginx nginx 0 Apr 18 22:11 www.sock
```

I added the two following lines in the file /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params because they were missing (I found this on a different topic)

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_script_name;
```

But I still have my issue.
I'm stuck now so if anybody have an idea I would appreciate :-)

Of course, PHP and Nginx are well started with the proper user

```
[root@vps263501 ~]# ps aux | grep php
root      2913  0.0  0.3 317080  6464 ?        Ss   Apr18   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-fpm.conf)
nginx     2914  0.0  0.4 319436  8460 ?        S    Apr18   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     2915  0.0  0.4 319436  8460 ?        S    Apr18   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     2916  0.0  0.4 319436  8460 ?        S    Apr18   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     2917  0.0  0.4 319436  8460 ?        S    Apr18   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     2918  0.0  0.4 319436  8460 ?        S    Apr18   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     3705  0.0  0.4 319436  8460 ?        S    Apr18   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
root      9259  0.0  0.0 103304   892 pts/0    S+   00:09   0:00 grep php
[root@vps263501 ~]# ps aux | grep nginx
nginx     2914  0.0  0.4 319436  8460 ?        S    Apr18   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     2915  0.0  0.4 319436  8460 ?        S    Apr18   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     2916  0.0  0.4 319436  8460 ?        S    Apr18   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     2917  0.0  0.4 319436  8460 ?        S    Apr18   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     2918  0.0  0.4 319436  8460 ?        S    Apr18   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     3705  0.0  0.4 319436  8460 ?        S    Apr18   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
root      4168  0.0  0.1  45556  2140 ?        Ss   Apr18   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
nginx     6115  0.0  0.1  45560  2324 ?        S    Apr18   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      9261  0.0  0.0 103304   892 pts/0    S+   00:09   0:00 grep nginx
```

It might be trivial but I have to admit that I'm confused...
Thanks for your help !

Comment: change this `unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock` to `unix: /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;` and show what happend

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I still have the same logs errors. I tried several location for the php7.0-fpm.sock (/var/run/php /var/run/php-fpm/) but I still have the same logs...

`2016/04/19 21:56:32 [error] 10376#0: *367 upstream sent invalid status "20 Site temporairement indisponible" while reading response header from upstream, client: 86.253.24.233, server: testvps.balusson.net, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "testvps.balusson.net"`

Answer (score 0):

Change socket to 127.0.0.1:9000 in php-fpm and the restart php-fpm.
Then try the following settings in your nginx website conf:

```
location / {
        root /var/www/maisonrt2012/public_html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        #error_page 404 404.html;

    }
```

restart nginx and try it out. Don't forget: www-data may need read and execute Permission to your php files.

Had the same issue. I tried it with brute forcing :P.
Maybe this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else browsing StackOverflow hits this issue again, I can see that this sort of thing is mentioned in many places, e.g.

https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?3,129805,129811

https://forum.directadmin.com/threads/php-fpm-5-6-and-7-0-error-restart-every-minute.54709/

There are multiple possible causes, but I did find one that caused the issue in our system. I had monit set up to restart processes if they failed. I had a custom monit config file that looked for the php-fpm socket. We updated php-fpm from PHP 7.3 to 7.4 and the name of the socket file changed. So monit decided that php-fpm wasn't running and restarted it every minute. Changing the monit config file fixed the problem.